# YII2 ad html tags to dropdownlist

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2, jquery-select2

i've create dropdownlist  like this :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'doctor_id')->widget(select2::className(),[
   'data'=>  arrayhelper::map(\app\models\doctors::find()->asArray()->all(),'doctor_id',
        function($model, $defaultValue) {
          return $model['doctor_name'].' | '. $model['doctor_id'].' | '. $model['phone1'] ;
}),
 // 'languge'=>'en',
   'options'=>['placeholder'=>'... إختر اسم الطبيب','class' => 'yuorClass'],
   'pluginOptions'=>[
   'allowClear'=>true
   ],
   ])?>
```

so i need to add html tag between the rows like `<br>` like this  `$model['doctor_name'].' - '. $model['doctor_id'].' <br> '. $model['phone1'] ;`

as the picture in here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i did't found what i was looking for , and i changed my idea : i used auto complete from YII2 itself :

in Controller :

```
$patients = patient::find()->select(['concat(patient_id)  as value','  concat("(",patient_id,") ","(",mobile,") ",patient_name)  as  label','patient_id as id'])->asArray()->all();
```

In my view.php

```
use yii\jui\AutoComplete;
use yii\web\JsExpression; 


echo AutoComplete::widget([ 
            'class'=> 'form-control',
            'clientOptions' => [
            'class'=> 'form-control',
            'source' => $patients,
            'minLength'=>'1', 
            'autoFill'=>true,
            'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
                            $('#memberssearch-family_name_id').val(ui.item.id);
                            document.location = '?r=patient1/view&id='+ui.item.id;
                        }")],
                         'options'=>[
                                    'class'=>'form-control',
                                    'placeholder'=>'بحث باسم المريض',
            ],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what i was looking for today in `krajee select2` [here](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-templates)